# grails linkGenerator controller variable

Tags: url, grails, hyperlink

When I try to call grailsLinkGenerator.link()   I input passwordReset for the controller variable, but when I check the url it is converted to password-reset

Why is this happening and how do i stop it ( i want it to transmit as passwordReset)

Comment: Can you show what you're using for the call? Is it something like:grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'passwordReset', action: 'show', id: 100, absolute: true)

Comment: If so - do you actually HAVE a passwordReset controller?  Or is that the action?

Comment: Share your code, it will help to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are correct about `passwordReset` being the `controller` name for (`PasswordResetController.groovy`) and not the `action`, then verify whether you have this property in `Config.groovy`:

`grails.web.url.converter = 'hyphenated'`

This property makes sure that the url pattern is customized to hypenated instead of default camel case. Generally, url patterns are:

`myDummy/myDummyAction` for controller `MyDummyController.groovy` and action `myDummyAction`

After adding the property, the url pattern changes to

`my-dummy/my-dummy-action` for controller `MyDummyController.groovy` and action `myDummyAction`